# Python: plot dataframe of datetime entries

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

My data looks like this :

```
    900324492   900405679   900472531
1   2017-04-03 08:04:09 2017-04-03 07:49:53 2017-04-03 07:52:39
2   2017-04-03 08:05:36 2017-04-03 07:54:36 2017-04-03 07:52:19
3   2017-04-03 08:05:28 2017-04-03 07:43:00 2017-04-03 07:50:52
4   2017-04-03 08:06:05 2017-04-03 07:49:42 2017-04-03 07:53:55
```

So, for each column, I have a set of time stamps (datetime objects, to be exact). I like to make a scatter plot, where x is the df index or row number (i.e.  `x=[1,2,3,4,...])`, and y is a time point. For example, If there are 4 rows and 10 columns in df, x axis should be `1, 2, 3, 4`, and
for `x=1` there should be one point per entry in the first row.

It seemed like a simple task, but I'm struggling a bit. My code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df2 = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x))

fig = plt.figure()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
y = df2.ix[:, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
x = df2.index.values
# returns nonsense
ax.plot(x,y)
# TypeError: invalid type promotion
ax.scatter(x=x, y = df2.ix[:,1])
# TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
df2.ix[:,1].plot()
```

Test file link : [test.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zhmt2cdn3e8rxt/test.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my example from yours. You should focus on `to_pydatetime()` and `date2num()` and `np.nan`. (You have to tag y axis to datetime format finally.)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)
df2 = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x))

fig = plt.figure()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
y = df2.ix[:, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
x = df2.index.values

def fix(x):
    try:
        return dates.date2num(x.to_pydatetime())
    except:
        return np.nan

y_lab = [str(e) for e in y]
y_ = [fix(e) for e in y]

ax.scatter(x=x, y=y_)

plt.yticks(y_, y_lab, rotation=0, size=6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But you see the y axis? It is not easy to interpret it, which kinda contradicts the motivation for doing it. Is there a way to fix it, so that it shows time, instead of decimals?

Comment: You can use `num2date()` function for ylabel.

Comment: I will show you an example after 3 hours! (AFK and currently mobile) So please hold on.

Comment: Updated, sorry for late.