# Struggling with simple X, Y scatter in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to pandas and am struggling with a dumb  scatter plotting.

I want to have dates as column and times plotted how do I do it?

```
data = [('04/22', 9), ('04/22', 5), ('04/22', 7), ('04/22', 20), ('04/21', 14), ('04/21', 9), ('04/21', 7), ('04/21', 12), ('04/21', 9), ('04/21', 5)]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date', 'Time'])

print(df)
df.groupby('Date')
df.plot(x='Date', y='Time')
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: So what happens when you try to plot it?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide how to deal with the string(I mean placing '04/22', '04/21', ... on x-axis based on what?). I'll show you a simple example and more complicated one.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [('04/22', 9), ('04/22', 5), ('04/22', 7), ('04/22', 20), ('04/21', 14), ('04/21', 9), ('04/21', 7), ('04/21', 12), ('04/21', 9), ('04/21', 5)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Time'])

# I decided just using integer of index.
df = df.groupby('Date').sum().reset_index().reset_index()
df.plot.scatter(x='index', y='Time')

y_lab = [str(e) for e in df['Date']]
plt.xticks(df.index, y_lab, rotation=0, size=6)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And If you want to use datetime index, check my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197511/python-plot-dataframe-of-datetime-entries/43197693#43197693). And I think maybe this is more useful to you eventually.

[image]